# Angular 2 material Stepper is not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

Hi I am working on an Angular 2 project and using material modules a lot. For some reason i cant able to even import the Stepper module to my project. So I endup importing the entire material modules as below:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { StepperComponent } from './stepper.component';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';


@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, MaterialModule],
  declarations: [StepperComponent],
  exports: [StepperComponent]
})

export class StepperModule {}
```

and i used it in my html just as below to test its imported

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper></mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Then I am getting the following error,

```
polyfills.dll.js:24743 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'mat-horizontal-stepper' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-horizontal-stepper' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-horizontal-stepper' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<mat-horizontal-stepper></mat-horizontal-stepper>"): t@0:0 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
```

I able to use a lot of material modules. Only problem with this one. Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your app.module.ts code. Are you using the <mat-horizontal-stepper> in the StepperComponent?

Comment: yes as mentioned in my question am using `<mat-horizontal-stepper>`. Nothing to do with `app.module.ts ` right since `StepperModule` is importing the materialmodule.

Comment: The stepper component was introduced from `2.0.0-beta.11`, which ended support for `MaterialModule`. **(Did you even read the changelog??)**

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you are importing the modules correctly? Make sure that in your `app.module.ts`, you have the import to `MatStepperModule` and **NOT** `MaterialModule` (which was removed from `2.0.0-beta.11`, see [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-1)):

```ts
import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MatStepperModule,
        // ...
    ]
})
```

The reason why it did not work is because the stepper component was a new addition from `2.0.0-beta.11` (see the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2.0.0-beta.11) for more info and as said above, removes `MaterialModule`)

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem.

The reason for me was that I was reading the documentation for Angular Material 12.1.1 which advices to use the `mat-stepper` component selector with the orientation binding.

In my project, I was actually using Angular Material 9.2.4 which used the old component `mat-horizontal-stepper` selector.

So try checking the Angular Material version you are using against the relevant version of the documentation,

Answer (score 2):

The issue was, that I used Angular bootstrap with Angular material. They don't seem to work with one another. That seems to be the reason whey it never worked for me.

Instead of `mat-stepper` use `mat-horizontal-stepper`.